# GeoDjango distance query weighted by rating

Tags: django-models, postgis, geodjango

I am using GeoDjango/PostGIS and have a model called Business that has a physical location and a rating. I would like to run a query to find 'nearest' highly rated businesses. How do I do this? To make it more concrete, suppose given a location, I want to find  businesses sorted by rating/(1+distance). What is the best way to go about this?

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Business(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     rating = models.IntegerField()
     address = models.PointField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can sort by min distance in geodjango, but you can filter by distance, and only get the ones near of your point, and then order by rating.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
pnt = Point(954158.1, 4215137.1, srid=32140)
pnt.buffer(23) #radius
business = Business.objects.filter(address__intersects=pnt).order_by('rating')
```

In  postgis you could get what you are asking for with a simple query like this:

```
SELECT name, rating, 
ST_Distance(the_geom,ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(19.232 91.00)') AS minDist 
FROM business ORDER BY minDist,rating;
```